# MySQL script inside set statement

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I got a hint from O.jones and went to create a  stored function.

That's what I created:

DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION change_int(colres VARCHAR(500)) RETURNS INT(11)
    BEGIN

```
    DECLARE res int(11);
    DECLARE leng int(11);
    DECLARE newres int(11);
    DECLARE mult int(11);
    DECLARE temp1 int(11);
    DECLARE temp2 int(11);  

SET res = CAST(colres AS UNSIGNED);
SET leng = CHAR_LENGTH(CAST( colres AS CHAR)); 
SET newres = 0;
SET mult = 1;
SET temp1 = 0;
SET temp2 = 0;


WHILE (res > 0) DO

    SET temp1 = MOD(res , 10 );
    SET res = (res DIV 10);
    SET temp2 = MOD(res , 10 );
    SET newres = (newres +((temp1 + temp2 ) * mult));       
    SET mult = mult*10;
END WHILE;
SET newres = SUBSTRING (newres, 1, leng );
RETURN newres;  
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

But I get error when I ty to run it  on line 6 :

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''res' = CAST(colres AS CHAR)' at line 6
```

Added a delimiter, new error:

```
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET newres = SUBSTRING (newres, 1, leng );
    RETURN newres;    
    END' at line 27
```

Greate now it worked. 
But I can not evoke her:

Ran a test with:

```
SHOW FUNCTION STATUS;
```

And it exists.

When I try to ran it like this:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `col1` = function_name(`col1`);
```

Also tried:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `col1` = db.function_name(`col1`);
```

No luck.

Comment: This kind of thing is called a *stored function.* The intertoobz have many examples and tutorials.

Comment: @O.Jones thank you so much, it really gave me a direction. 
Could you please look why is my statement getting an error?

Comment: Have you read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html and have you set delimiters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missing column before `END WHILE`. It must be `END WHILE;`

[Working example](https://rextester.com/CWS50484)

Comment: One last thing, cant seem to call it. tried: 
UPDATE `gd_accounts` SET `account_number` = change_int(`account_number`);
UPDATE `gd_accounts` SET `account_number` = db_name.change_int(`account_number`);

GET: 

#1630 - FUNCTION db_name.SUBSTRING does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual